# cron: What means mail error status "0x0002#012"

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cron job specified in the crontab:

```
...
MAILTO=root
...
...
47 09 * * * tst nice -n 15 /opt/tst/bin/doMirror
...
```

The doMirror script fails because of a syntax error. I had expected that the root user will become a email notification, but in the cron log stands:

```
Dec  4 09:47:01 f601 CROND[1163]: (CRON) ERROR chdir failed (/home/tst): Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Dec  4 09:47:01 f601 CROND[1161]: (tst) MAIL (mailed 60 bytes of output but got status 0x0002#012)
```

What means "got status 0x0002#012". Cannot find any information about that.

If I send a email via

```
echo "This is only a test." | mail -s "Testing testing" root
```

this works like expected.

Thanks,
Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The reason why the email could not be send is, that the user "tst" has in my case no own and already created home directory. After create the home directory for user tst it works like expected! :-)